# Ask for help in proofreading a book

Tags: discussion

In case, one had written a book manuscript, but it was not possible to find, by other means, proofreaders mathematically knowledgeable enough to proofread the manuscript, would it be appropriate to ask on MathOverflow for volunteers doing the proofreading?

In the case at hand the manuscript (in German) is already accepted by a publisher, but the publisher says, they can not provide in depth proofreading because the book is too specialized/advanced and so the copy-editor will probably only check spelling, grammar and superficial consistency.

Comment: In my opinion, the answer is no. MathOverflow is the wrong forum for that, and I suspect there is no good place on StackExchange for such a request. That said, I have a subtle advertisement for proofreading services on my MathOverflow user page, and others might advertise similarly. The only way I see getting volunteer (no money) help is if the subject has appeal to the volunteer. In which case, individual requests by email to a hand-picked group might succeed.  Gerhard "German Is My Third Language" Paseman, 2019.04.17.

Comment: Of course, you might also [ask in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=mathoverflow.net)  - restrictions what is on-topic are much more relaxed in chat. (Whether there is a reasonable chance that you find something - be it by asking here or in chat - is a separate question.)

Comment: Somewhat similar question on Mathematics Meta: [Inviting people to proofread a mathematical text allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25798)

Comment: Presumably the publisher is offering payment for this.  In principle we could offer that service.  For example, Stack Overflow hosts a "jobs" tag.  But (as noted) currently we do not.